# WPF ComboBox autocomplete from items

Tags: wpf, combobox, autocomplete

I have a ComboBox where I load in every hour and minute constellation possible.
This gives many items and to still keep this user friendly I want an autocomplete. But the thing is when I turn `IsEditable="true"` a user can also enter any value.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbStartZeit" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" />
```

I add the items in two for loops

```
for(int i = 00; i <= 24; i++)
{
    for(int j = 00; j <= 59; j++)
    {
       cmbStartZeit.Items.Add(i.ToString("00") + ":" + j.ToString("00"));
    }
}
```

How can I turn the autocomplete feature on without allowing the user to add custom values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if combobox items contains entered text in `TextChanged` event.
So xaml code looks like this.

```
<ComboBox Name="cbTest" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True"
          TextBoxBase.TextChanged="cbTest_TextChanged" />
```

And the code behinde should look like this. This code prevents user input, that not in combobox items.

```
string _prevText = string.Empty;

private void cbTest_TextChanged( object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e )
{
    foreach ( var item in cbTest.Items )
    {
        if ( item.ToString().StartsWith( cbTest.Text ) )
        {
            _prevText = cbTest.Text;
            return;
        }
    }
    cbTest.Text = _prevText;
}
```